# Sorting all files and folders by size C#

Tags: c#, linq, file, sorting

I'm trying to write some code that sorts all files and folders on a system by size and put that in a txt file. E.g...

```
/Users: 25Gb
    /Users/me: 20Gb
        /Users/me/films: 11Gb
            /Users/me/films/Shrek.mkv 6Gb
            /Users/me/films/Shrek2.mkv 5Gb
        /Users/me/Documents: 9Gb
            /Users/me/Documents: myBigFile.rar 5Gb
            /Users/me/Documents: mySmallerFile.rar 4Gb
    /Users/mum: 5Gb
        /Users/mum/documents: 5Gb
            /Users/mum/documents: mumsFile.zip 5Gb
```

You get the picture - Folders sorted by size and all of their subfolders/files sorted by files as well (maybe with indents like above). So far my code (below) gets all files from all folders in my downloads and sorts those, then puts the total size at the end of the file. Does anyone know where I could go from here? Thanks!

```
static void ProcessDirectory(string writeTo, string inPath)
    {
        var Sort = Directory.EnumerateFiles(inPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            .OrderByDescending(f => new FileInfo(f).Length);

        long b = 0;
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(writeTo, true);

        foreach (string name in Sort)
        {

            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
            long len = info.Length;
            tw.WriteLine(name + ": " + len);
            b += info.Length;
            }


        tw.WriteLine(b);
        tw.Close();
        // 4.
        // Return total size
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string outPath = @"/Users/a/Documents/size.txt";
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(outPath, true); //This must come first to create the file

        ProcessDirectory(outPath, @"/Users/a/Downloads");
        tw.Close();
    }
```

Comment: So basically try to reinvent TreeSize?

Comment: Use recursion to do it. Look for examples online and you will find thousands of them.

Comment: Or a `.GroupBy([DirectoryName])` on the directories enumeration and then iterate the items in the groupings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get you somewhere

**Given**

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    static readonly string[] _sizeSuffixes ={ "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };

    public static string ToSize(this long value, int decimalPlaces = 1)
    {
        if (value < 0) { return "-" + ToSize(-value); }

        var i = 0;
        var dValue = (decimal)value;
        while (Math.Round(dValue, decimalPlaces) >= 1000)
        {
            dValue /= 1024;
            i++;
        }

        return string.Format("{0:n" + decimalPlaces + "} {1}", dValue, _sizeSuffixes[i]);
    }
}
```

**Class**

```
public class Info
{
    public Info(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        DirectoryInfo = directoryInfo;
        Name = directoryInfo.FullName;
    }
    public Info(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        Name = fileInfo.FullName;
        Size = fileInfo.Length;
    }
    public DirectoryInfo DirectoryInfo { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long Size { get; set; }
    public List<Info> Children { get; set; } = new List<Info>();
    public List<Info> GetDirectories()
    {
        if (DirectoryInfo == null) return Children;

        var dirs = DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
                                .Select(x => new Info(x))
                                .ToList();
        Children = dirs;
        Children.AddRange(DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles().Select(x => new Info(x)));
        return dirs;
    }


    public void Order()
    {
        if (Children == null) return;
        Children = Children.OrderBy(x => x.Children == null).ThenByDescending(x => x.Size).ToList();
        Children.ForEach(c => c.Order());
    }

    public void Sum() => Size = Children?.Sum(x => x.Size) ?? 0;

    public void WriteResults(StreamWriter fs, int level =0)
    {
        fs.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', level)}{Name} {Size.ToSize(3)}");
        level++;
        if (Children == null) return;
        foreach (var info in Children)
            info.WriteResults(fs, level);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var info = ProcessDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\"));

    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Reuslts.txt", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            info.Sum();
            info.Order();
            info.WriteResults(sw);
        }
    }
}

private static Info ProcessDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var baseInfo = new Info(directoryInfo);
    var queue = new Queue<Info>();
    queue.Enqueue(baseInfo);

    while (queue.Count>0) 
    {
        try
        {
            var info = queue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var dir in info.GetDirectories())
                queue.Enqueue(dir);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e) { }
    }

    return baseInfo;
}
```